# Unable to Create EndPoint with RxJava and Reterofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am following [Github Link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) to consume API using ReteroFit and RxJava but while changing type from Call to Observer in my Interface Class I am getting an error message.

> Type 'java.util.Observable' doesnot have type parameters

**ApiClient:**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "*********";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        if (retrofit==null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

**ApiInterface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("user/get_user")
    Observable<UserResponse> getUsers(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);

}
```

**UserResponse:**

```
public class UserResponse {

    private List<User> result;
    private String status_message;
    private int status_code;

    public int getStatus_code() {
        return status_code;
    }

    public void setStatus_code(int status_code) {
        this.status_code = status_code;
    }

    public List<User> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<User> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getStatus_message() {
        return status_message;
    }

    public void setStatus_message(String status_message) {
        this.status_message = status_message;
    }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 14):

Change `import java.util.Observable;` in your code to `import io.reactivex.Observable;`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong Observable class:

Type 'j**ava.util**.Observable'

instead of using the rx java Obserable

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answers said, wrong, import to remedy this, delete the import, then `alt + enter` to import new one.

Logging interceptor for future logging.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
```

Comment: make sure to hover over the observable to import

Comment: also I would recommend using retrofit logging interceptors to log network requests